# Multi-column sorting for a repeat control having its source as document collection

Tags: sorting, xpages, repeater, multiple-columns

Don't know whether it is possible but is there way in which I could provide multi-column sorting in a repeat control which displays field values from a document collection?

Comment: Within reason, almost anything is possible in an XPage... it's just a question of how much code you're willing to write yourself to get behavior that IBM hasn't already bundled into a single icon for you. For a glimpse of what's possible for sorting data, learn about comparators: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html However, before you write a complex comparator to deliver this use case, evaluate whether your users might be better served by smarter search or an export to Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the multi-column sorting is to use a Data Grid.

Out of the Extension Library box you can use the Dojo Data Grid control. Brad Balassaitis wrote a good description how to use it in his [blog Xcellerant](http://xcellerant.net/dojo-grids-in-xpages/). There you can find a link to an example database too. A good starting point is the XPages "REST_DojoGrid" in database XPagesExt.nsf which is included in [Extlib download](http://extlib.openntf.org/) also.

As an alternative you could use data grids based on jQuery like [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could do a lot of complicated stuff, like putting docs into a java TreeMap object in order to sort them on the fly.

Or you simply use jQuery and the tablesorter plugin: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: But the tablesorter plugin only sorts visible data. So if you have more data in the backend and want to change the displayed data based on sorting, then tablesorter is not the way to go

Comment: True! Nash didn't say how much data he wants to display and if he wants to use pagers :-)

Comment: Glad that we agree :-)

Comment: Thanks Julian the table-sorter looks like is a good tool for data display and sorting but I also need inline editing with that and hence I will have to agree with Kunt's answer here. I guess the data grid is the quickest way to achieve the kind of stuff I looking out for. Brad has indeed gone into quit a bit of detail in explaining the data gird on his blog.